# Cardinal.continue is not working in IE 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to implement the songbird.js file in my application. I could see that the `cardinal.continue` method is not triggering in IE11 alone. And I am getting the error below.

I am getting the error below in the framework level itself.

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
File: songbird.js, Line: 1, Column: 1148
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 common ways to trigger the **SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number** JavaScript error in earlier versions of Internet Explorer.

The first way is to include a trailing comma after your last property in a JavaScript object.

The other common trigger is using a JavaScript reserved word as a property name.

The solution is to pass the class property value as a string. You will need to use bracket notation, however, to call the property in your script.

Reference:

[Fix an error SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number](http://mikemclin.net/fixing-error-script1028-expected-identifier-string-or-number/)

Comment: Also I found another solution that, Since IE is using the IE7 setting by default. Since Cardinal Js is not supported in IE7 I have made my code to make ie to support ie 11 via meta tag and its working for me.